# Proving the following conditions are equivalent: $|a_n-a|<\epsilon$, $|a_n-a| \leq \epsilon $

Tags: limits, analysis

Proving 
$ \forall _{\epsilon>0} \exists _{n_0 \in \mathbb N} \forall _{n\geq n_0}|a_n-a|<\epsilon $

$\forall _{\eta>0} \exists _{N \in \mathbb N} \forall _{n\geq N} |a_n-a|\leq \epsilon $

What to do first?

Comment: I think that $\eta$ is a typo...

Comment: Obviously $<$ implies $\le$. Thus, you can consider only the oher part.

Answer (score 0):

Preassuming that the second condition ends with $\cdots\leq\eta$

The first conditions implies the second condition immediately.

Conversely if $\epsilon>0$ then take $\eta=\frac12\epsilon$.

Then according the second condition some $n_0\in\mathbb N$ will exists with $|a_n-a|\leq\eta<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq n_0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let

$(1) \quad \forall _{\epsilon>0} \exists _{n_0 \in \mathbb N} \forall _{n\geq n_0}|a_n-a|<\epsilon$

and

$(2) \quad \forall _{\epsilon>0} \exists _{n_0 \in \mathbb N} \forall _{n\geq n_0}|a_n-a| \le \epsilon$.

It should be clear that $(1) $ implies $(2)$.

Now suppose that $(2)$ holds and let $ \epsilon >0$. By, $(2)$ we have

$\exists _{n_0 \in \mathbb N} \forall _{n\geq n_0}|a_n-a| \le \epsilon/2$.

Hence

$\exists _{n_0 \in \mathbb N} \forall _{n\geq n_0}|a_n-a| < \epsilon.$

Thus $(1)$ holds.